# Pandas error opening gzip file from URL

Tags: python, pandas, gzip

I'm trying to retrieve a gzipped csv from our server and load the file into a pandas dataframe.

In the pandas docs `pandas.read_csv` accepts  Valid URL schemes such as `http, ftp, s3, and file`. The link I'm using is an `https`, don't think that should cause an Issue.

I tried 2 ways of getting this to work.

Method 1:

```
import pandas as pd


print "Downloading file" 
link = 'https://myserver/logfile.csv.gz'

df = pd.read_csv(link, compression='gzip', header=0, sep=',', quotechar='"')

print df
```

This didn't work and I got the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download.py", line 14, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(link, compression='gzip', header=0, sep=',', quotechar='"')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.16.0_79_g9e4e447-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 470, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.16.0_79_g9e4e447-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 246, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.16.0_79_g9e4e447-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 562, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.16.0_79_g9e4e447-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 699, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.16.0_79_g9e4e447-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1066, in __init__
    self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 509, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/parser.c:4722)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 624, in pandas.parser.TextReader._get_header (pandas/parser.c:6111)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 820, in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas/parser.c:8142)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 1758, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas/parser.c:20728)
pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on source failed. Try engine='python'.
```

Then after some googling, I decided to try the following.

```
import urllib
import gzip
import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import requests

print "Downloading file" 
link = 'https://myserver/logfile.csv.gz'

r = requests.get(link)
gz = gzip.GzipFile(StringIO.StringIO(r.content))

df = pd.read_csv(gz, compression='gzip', header=0, sep=',', quotechar='"')

print df
```

and I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download.py", line 12, in <module>
    gz = gzip.GzipFile(StringIO.StringIO(r.content))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 89, in __init__
    fileobj = self.myfileobj = __builtin__.open(filename, mode or 'rb')
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found
```

Comment: `StringIO` create file object but `GzipFile` expects filename.